# Pyspark: How to create a table by crossing information in two columns?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like this in Pyspark:

```
A   1   info_A1
A   2   info_A2
B   2   info_B2
B   3   info_B3
```

I would like to obtain this result:

```
info_A1   null
info_A2   info_B2
null      info_B3
```

Is there any function in Pyspark that does it automatically or I should iterate each row separately?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupBy` and `pivot`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"x": "A", "y": 1, "z": "info_A1"},
    {"x": "A", "y": 2, "z": "info_A2"},
    {"x": "B", "y": 2, "z": "info_B2"},
    {"x": "B", "y": 3, "z": "info_B3"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = df.groupBy("y").pivot("x").agg(F.max("z")).orderBy("y").drop("y")
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+                                                               
|A      |B      |
+-------+-------+
|info_A1|null   |
|info_A2|info_B2|
|null   |info_B3|
+-------+-------+
```